# React native NativeBase setup

Tags: react-native, native-base

When installing NativeBase `npm install native-base --save`
I get this and my project don't work well

```
npm WARN rm not removing E:\ReactNative\Project\node_modules\.bin\jest.cmd as it wasn't installed by E:\ReactNative\Project\node_modules\jest
npm WARN rm not removing E:\ReactNative\Project\node_modules\.bin\jest as it wasn't installed by E:\ReactNative\Project\node_modules\jest
npm WARN rm not removing E:\ReactNative\Project\node_modules\.bin\json5.cmd as it wasn't installed by E:\ReactNative\Project\node_modules\json5
npm WARN rm not removing E:\ReactNative\Project\node_modules\.bin\json5 as it wasn't installed by E:\ReactNative\Project\node_modules\json5
npm WARN rm not removing E:\ReactNative\Project\node_modules\.bin\esparse.cmd as it wasn't installed by E:\ReactNative\Project\node_modules\esprima
npm WARN rm not removing E:\ReactNative\Project\node_modules\.bin\esvalidate.cmd as it wasn't installed by E:\ReactNative\Project\node_modules\esprima
npm WARN rm not removing E:\ReactNative\Project\node_modules\.bin\esparse as it wasn't installed by E:\ReactNative\Project\node_modules\esprima
npm WARN rm not removing E:\ReactNative\Project\node_modules\.bin\esvalidate as it wasn't installed by E:\ReactNative\Project\node_modules\esprima
```

Comment: I dont think this is because of NativeBase

Answer (score 0):

try update with:

```
 npm i
```

and if doesn't work check what file(s) or folder(s) delete or edited wrongly !

and then try `npm install native-base --save` and reinstall again...

when you want to build clean the project and rebuild it